# GraphQL - Cannot update a table row

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

Say I have a table Person with attributes `id` and `name`. The GraphQL server is all setup by `Postgraphile` and working as I can query and create new entry. However, I could not update it. Scratching my head over and over again and I am still unable to find out the cause for this.

This is the mutation I tried that failed me every now and then.

```
mutation($id: Int!, $patch: PersonPatch!) {
  updatePersonById(input: { id: $id, patch: $patch }) {
    clientMutationId
  }
}
```

The variables

```
{
    id: 1, 
    patch: {"name": "newname"}
}
```

I was using `Altair GraphQL client` to submit the mutation request and the error message returned was `"No values were updated in collection 'people' because no values were found."`

The person of `id = 1` does exist, confirmed by sending a query `personById` over to get his name. But I just couldn't update his name.

#### Edit #1

Below is the gql generated by `Altair GraphQL Client`

```
updatePersonById(
  input: UpdatePersonByIdInput!
): UpdatePersonPayload


input UpdatePersonByIdInput {
  clientMutationId: String
  patch: PersonPatch!
  id: Int!
}

input PersonPatch {
  id: Int
  name: String
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `updatePersonById` resolver in the question?

Comment: @nimish I have attached it in my edit #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using row-level security (RLS) it sounds like the row to be updated does not pass the required security policies for the currently authenticated user.

Here's a small example; you'll want to adjust it to fit your own permissions system

```sql
create table person (id serial primary key, name text);
alter table person enable row level security;
grant select, insert(name), update(name), delete on person to graphql;
create policy select_all on person for select using (true);
create policy insert_all on person for insert with check(true);
create policy update_self on person for update using (id = current_person_id());
create policy delete_self on person for delete using (id = current_person_id());
```

where

```sql
create function current_person_id() returns int as $$
  select nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.person_id', true), '')::int;
$$ language sql stable;
```

If you need more guidance, feel free to drop into [the Graphile chat](http://discord.gg/graphile).